# Jquery file upload not working for each row of asp.net repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have attached  jquery file upload button in each repeater row but on click file upload selected files display for first row only. For other rows only total files selected (count)display but progress bar for selected files not display Please help me i am learner in asp.net actually i am front end developer. Actually i have to use client side file uploader for multiple files in repeater..My code is as follows:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
.a{
display:none;
}
.input{
display:none;
margin-top: -17px;
margin-left: 176px;
width:34px;
}
.button {
    background: #25A6E1;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#25A6E1),color-stop(100%,#188BC0));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,#25A6E1 0%,#188BC0 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#25A6E1',endColorstr='#188BC0',GradientType=0);
    padding:8px 13px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;
    font-size:17px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #1A87B9;
    width:227px !important;
}   


</style>
 <script>

     var selDiv = "";
     var updateProcessInterval;
     var updateTextBoxInterval;

     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

     function init() {
         // var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("files");
         //  alert(classname);
         // document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
         var f = document.querySelectorAll('.files');
        // alert(f);
         for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
             //alert("jdj");
             //alert(f.length);
             f[i].addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, false);

             //alert(f[i]);
             /* for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
             alert(classname.length);
             classname[i].addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
             }*/
             //  $('.files').on("change", function(){ handleFileSelect(); });
         }
     }
     function handleFileSelect(e) {

         if (!e.target.files) return;

         var files = e.target.files;
        // alert(files);

         for (var i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {

             var progress = document.createElement("progress");
             progress.setAttribute('class', 'a');
             progress.setAttribute('id', 'i');
             progress.setAttribute('max', '100');
             progress.setAttribute('value', '0');
             var filename = document.createElement("div");

             var text = document.createElement("input");

             text.setAttribute('class', 'input');
             text.setAttribute('value', '0%');
             text.setAttribute('max', '100%');

             filename.setAttribute('class', 'filename');
             $('.prrogress-wp').append(filename);
            $('.progress-wpr').append(progress);
            $('.progress-wpr').append(text);
         }


         var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
         var filename = document.getElementsByClassName('filename');
         var textname = document.getElementsByClassName('input');
         for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

             var f = files[i];
             var p = elements[i];
             var t = textname[i];

             filename[i].innerHTML = f.name;
             p.style.display = 'block';
             t.style.display = 'block';

             updateProcessInterval = setInterval(update_progress, 1500);
             updateTextBoxInterval = setInterval(updatetextbox, 1500);
         }

     }
     function update_progress() {
         var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('a');

         for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
             var p = elements[i];


             var a = p.value;
             a = a + 10; //alert(a)// infinite number of times sum 
             if (a > 100) {  //if this part add then see
                 clearInterval(updateProcessInterval);
             }
             p.value = a; //alert(p.value);

         }
     }
     function updatetextbox() {
         var textt = document.getElementsByClassName('input');
         //alert(textt.length);  //any alert in this doc display right value but n no times
         for (var i = 0; i < textt.length; i++) {

             var tt = textt[i];
             // alert(textt[i]);
             var a = tt.value;
             c = parseInt(a) + parseInt("10");

             if (parseInt(c) > 100) {
                 clearInterval(updateTextBoxInterval);
                 return;
             } else if (!(parseInt(c) < 0 || isNaN(c))) {
                 tt.value = c + "%";
             }


         }
     }


    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1"   runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
        <HeaderTemplate>

    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
    <table id="gg">
    <tr class="ff">
    <td>
         <input type="file" class="button files"  id="files" name="files"  onchange="handleFileSelect(this)"  multiple><br/>
        <div id="progress-wpr" class="progress-wpr">
        <div class="filename"></div>
        <progress class='a'  max=100 value=0></progress>
        <input type="text" value="0%" class="input"  max="100" />

        </div>
        <input type="submit"  value="Upload" class="button" style="margin-top:56px;width:77px !important" >
          </td></tr></table>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:countryConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [countries]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Students1ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Students]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here:

```
   function init() {
                 // var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("files");
               //  alert(classname);
                  document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
                /* for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
                     alert(classname.length);
                     classname[i].addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
                 }*/
             }
```

document.querySelector('#files') is an ID selector and its attaching to the file inputs properly.  You should select all of the file inputs using the class name instead like so:

```
    var f = document.querySelectorAll('.files');
    for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
        f[i].addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, false);
}
```

Comment: i have already use class name in querySelector  but at  run time  error occurs:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Try the jquery way of adding the event listener:

$('.files').on("change", function(){ handleFileSelect(); });

if this works then I'll update the answer.

Comment: Now error is not coming but the fuction handleFileSelect() not calls for any repeater row. Progress bar not display for any row.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense since handleFileSelect is not expecting jquery objects.  You should stick with:  document.querySelector. However I just realized that document.querySelector only returns 1 item.  You need to use document.querySelectorAll() to return all items that match your selector.

Comment: yes i have also implement it but undefined is not a function error occurs in browser

Comment: in the browser, click on view source and post the source.

Comment: Srry but  handleFileSelect() not calls for each row and progress bar not created.Please help me.

Comment: actually progress bar  displays only in ist row of repeater but not work for other rows

Comment: I think your issue is here:              document.getElementById('progress-wpr').appendChild(filename);
             document.getElementById('progress-wpr').appendChild(progress);
             document.getElementById('progress-wpr').appendChild(text);  Again, you're selecting by ID and its find the first elemeith id=progress-wpr in the first row instead of the row it belongs to.

Comment: i have used class name  but it is not working actually i am unable to find out which browse button is clicked.I have updated my code .Please review it.